# Recovering deleted Gmail account

Tags: gmail, account-recovery

Can someone please let me know if I can reopen my old Gmail address?

I deleted it about 2 years ago.
I need to use this email again as I posted comments on YouTube video that
I need to look at again.  Very urgent.
Can you advise what I need to do to retrieve my old email address?
Your assistance would be appreciated.

If I cannot reuse this account, is it possible to at least view my old YouTube comments with the old Gmail address so I can see my comments?

Answer (score 2):

It is almost impossible to you to recover your account as you have deleted your account 2 years back.

There is some grace period (around 1 or 2 weeks) within that users can recover their account, but in your case it's impossible, still you can try steps provided on [Google Account Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6236295?hl=en) page.

If it doesn't help, you can consider [creating a replacement Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7564124).

Deleting Gmail account deletes all associated services like all emails, YouTube channels, comments etc.. So, if you will not be able to recover your account, you will not be able to use or see anything associated with that account.